# cURL command gives unmarshal JSON response

Tags: json, curl, post

I am using Windows 10 64bit and cURL version 7.68.0 in order to send a REST request as shown her:

```
C:\user\myUserName>curl -X POST http://IPaddress:port/product/example --data '{}' --header "Content-type: application/json"
```

... sorry I can not show the IP address and port as this is a company data. But I hope it is clear what I mean here.

I am sure many of you have used this cURL command and that is why I ask in this forum here. Please let med know if you need any other info to make you able to answer my question.

When I execute the command above I get this response:

```
{"_type":"ValidationErrorMessage","issues":[{"_type":"ValidationErrorIssue","message":"Cannot unmarshal JSON as STRING"}]}
```

... the STRING is a hidden name again I hide it because it is a company data.

The expected response is: **"a string"**

I have tried to google the response I get and unfortunately I could not find any. That is why I ask here.

My questions are:

1. Is there any error with the syntax of the cURL command?
2. Why I get the `Cannot unmarshal JSON as ...`?
3. What am I supposed to change in order to avoid it and get the?

Thanks in advance for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Cannot unmarshal JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637969/cannot-unmarshal-json). In order to have the question just ones, you may edit your original post and the additional information there or remove it an leave just this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sloved:
The reason why I got the "cannot unmarshal JSON" is because of the '{}'. Removed the '' from curly brackets and it worked. i.e
C:\user\myUserName>curl -X POST http://IPaddress:port/product/example --data {} --header "Content-type: application/json"